# Category count including children from

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a script, that can make a multidimensional array have counts of a category's number of product uniquely assign to that category (cat_count) AND a count of the total of products in the category *including* its childreng categories.

I am have a  multidimensional array, that approximately looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Cars
            [ParentID] => 0
            [CategoryCount] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 1
            [CategoryName] => Zoo Animals
            [ParentID] => 0
            [CategoryCount] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 6
                            [CategoryName] => Lions
                            [ParentID] => 1
                            [CategoryCount] => 3
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 2
                            [CategoryName] => Elephants
                            [ParentID] => 1
                            [CategoryCount] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [CategoryID] => 3
                                            [CategoryName] => African Elephants
                                            [ParentID] => 2
                                            [CategoryCount] => 2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 5
                            [CategoryName] => Zebra
                            [ParentID] => 1
                            [CategoryCount] => 3
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The script, that creates this array, is:

```
public function build($d, $r = 0, $pk = 'parent', $k = 'id', $c = 'children')
{
    $m = array();

    foreach ($d as $e)
    {
        isset($m[$e[$pk]]) ?: $m[$e[$pk]] = array();
        isset($m[$e[$k]]) ?: $m[$e[$k]] = array();
        $m[$e[$pk]][] = array_merge($e, array($c => &$m[$e[$k]]));
    }

    return $m[$r];
}
```

Now what I want to do is to add AN EXTRA key to each array-item:
SumCategoryCount => // Holding the SUM of EACH item INCLUDING the count of its children.
E.g. The count for "Zoo Animal" would be 10 (1 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3).

I can't get how to do this - help is very appreciated.

Best Regards,

Denlaucr.

Comment: So, show us a script that creates such array.

Comment: u_mulder: Yeah of course.. I am a bit confused at the moment. It has been added now :)